# Plot binomial confidence intervals with plotrix

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval, plotrix

I need to add binomial confidence intervals to my plot.

Here are my steps:

```
library(binom)
library(plotrix)
x <- c(1:6)
y <- c(68, 69, 70, 75, 75, 87)

CI <- binom.confint(y, 265, conf.level = 0.95, methods = "exact")
plot(x, y)
plotCI(x, y, ui = CI$upper, li = CI$lower, add = TRUE)
```

I think I did everything correctly but my output plot doesn't seem right:

[image: output plot]

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binom.confint` returns confidence intervals on the *proportions*, not on the total numbers (if you'd inspected the `CI` object by printing it, you might have noticed this).  Try

```
plotCI(x,y,ui=CI$upper*CI$n,li=CI$lower*CI$n)
```

(This combines your two plotting statements to plot the points and the error bars at the same time.)

Alternatively you could plot the proportions and their CIs:

```
plotCI(x,y/CI$n,ui=CI$upper,li=CI$lower)
```

Comment: thanks! your answer sounds reasonable and worked. I will wait just a bit and after will select you as best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken into account the option of using ggplot2?
`geom_smooth` gives you the 95% confidence level interval for predictions from a linear model ("lm").

```
data<-data.frame(y=c(20.7, 18, 21.4, 15.3, 27.3, 20),x=c(1:6))
library(ggplot2)
g<-ggplot(data,aes(x,y))
g+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

The output will be:

[image]